# loop over characters in r for ggbiplot / ggplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, ggbiplot

It might sound stupid but:

I have a list for every country BE, AT, DE, etc. that I have performed pca, in a loop:

```
countries <- c("BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR",
               "HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT",
               "RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK")

for (x in countries){
  pca_list[[x]] <_ prcomp(pcaData_list[[x]], scale=TRUE)
}
```

Next I want a nice biplot, so I am using a ggbiplot from github("vqv/ggbiplot"), so I put the ggbiplot in the loop and I have the following:

```
for (x in countries){
  pca_list[[x]] <- prcomp(pcaData_list[[x]],scale=TRUE)
  ggbiplot(pca_list$x,scale=1,varname.size =0,varname.abbrev=1)
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I have tried replacing the `pca_list$x` with `paste0("pca_list$",x)` in the ggbiplot command but it still doesn't work.

Both tries give me an error:

> Expected a object of class prcomp, princomp, PCA, or lda

Further, when I do the same for one country in specific, say AT I do get a result.

```
ggbiplot(pca_list$AT,scale=1,varname.size =0,varname.abbrev=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `$` operator to access the elements of a list does not allow variable substitution. So when you specify `pca_list$x`, R searches for an item in the list literally labeled "x", which does not exist (and is therefore of class "NULL"). You probably need to change the code to:

```
for (x in countries){
  pca_list[[x]] <- prcomp(pcaData_list[[x]],scale=TRUE)
  ggbiplot(pca_list[[x]],scale=1,varname.size =0,varname.abbrev=1) # note the change here
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work, because even for one country, I have to declare it as:

pca_list$DE, pca_list[[DE]] does not work for some reason. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: would it be any possible way to make R search for   x in countries such as: ggbiplot(pca_list$paste0("",x),scale=1,varname.size =0,varname.abbrev=1)

This also doesn't work btw

Comment: I think you may have been confused by the code snippet I originally chose. I have updated my answer with a more complete loop.